# unable to use applyMiddleWare in redux

Tags: reactjs, npm, import, redux

Iam a newbie to redux.I imported createStore,combineReducers from redux and these work fine.

```
import {createStore,combineReducers} from "redux";
```

But iam unable to use applyMiddleWare

```
import {createStore,combineReducers,applyMiddleWare} from "redux";
```

The error is

**./src/index.js
63:101-116 'redux' does not contain an export named 'applyMiddleWare'.**

and when i try to import like this

```
import applyMiddleWare,{createStore,combineReducers} from "redux";
```

It shows

**./src/index.js
63:101-116 "export 'default' (imported as 'applyMiddleWare') was not found in 'redux'**

I did not change or modified any packages.
My Package.json shows dependencies as

```
"dependencies": {
"react": "^16.4.0",
"react-dom": "^16.4.0",
"react-redux": "^5.0.7",
"react-scripts": "1.1.4",
"redux":"^4.0.0",
"redux-logger": "3.0.6"
}
```

Advance thanks for helping!!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The 'w' in the applyMiddleWare should be small while importing. applyMiddleware

So you should import like:

```
import { applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
```

Comment: Yeah, just a typo mistake.